# EF code first, polymorphism cast

Tags: database, polymorphism, ef-code-first

I have a project with a person and a registered person

```
public class Person : BaseClass
    {
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Team> ParentTeams { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Team> ChildTeams { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public bool IsChildPerson { get; set; }
    }

public class RegisteredPerson : Person
    {
        public int ProxyId { get; set; }
    }
```

Registered person inherits person.

At a certain point the person becomes a registered person. But the person is allready bound to a team.

How can I cast the Person to a registered person, without losing the links to the other databases ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't cast downwards. What you could do is use a mapping library like [automapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) to map your **Person** object to a **RegisteredPerson** and then use the context to save.

Example:

```
using AutoMapper;

//Create Map from Person to RegisteredPerson
Mapper.CreateMap<Person, RegisteredPerson>();

//Load person from Database
Person p = context.Persons.SingleOrDefault(predicate);
//Map Person to RegisteredPerson
RegisteredPerson r = Mapper.Map<Person, RegisteredPerson>(p);
//Assign values to RegisteredPerson
r.ProxyId = SomeValue;
using (var context = new YourContext())
{
    context.Persons.Attach(r);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
//Load new RegisteredPerson
using (var context = new YourContext())
{
    RegisteredPerson rp = context.Persons.OfType<RegisteredPerson>().SingleOrDefault(predicate);
}
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies in this sentence:

> At a certain point the person becomes a registered person

In static OOP, an instance of a class cannot "become" a different class.

Do not use inheritance for that. Instead, store an `IsRegistered` flag.